# C# how to search in Dictionary key by array of tags

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio

I am learning c# and I am trying something simple: inputing some tags separated by comma the code to return a message. The idea is that the code should filter by all the tags that I am splitting into an array.

Defining the variables:

```
Dictionary<string[], string> messages = new Dictionary<string[], string>();
messages.Add(new string[] { "greeting", "hello", "hei", "hi" }, "Hello!");
messages.Add(new string[] { "greeting", "bye", "buh-bye", "sayonara" }, "Bye!");
```

Getting the tag:

```
string[] tags;
tags.Add("greeting");
tags.Add("hello");
```

The list and iterating:

```
List<string> lista = new List<string>();
foreach(string tag in e.GetArg("Tag").Split(','))
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string[], string> entry in gifs)
    {
        if (entry.Key.Contains(tag))
        {
            lista.Add(entry.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that it adds every met item for each tag in the **list**, even the bye item. Can I filter this with an array of tags? Or I need to pass it more times, each time getting the desired one(s)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Search Dictionary by key array

```
        Dictionary<string[], string> messages = new Dictionary<string[], string>();
        messages.Add(new string[] { "greeting", "hello", "hei", "hi" }, "Hello!");
        messages.Add(new string[] { "greeting", "bye", "buh-bye", "sayonara" }, "Bye!");

        // add tags
        string[] tags = new string[2];
        tags[0] = "greeting";
        tags[1] = "buh-bye";

        List<string> lista = new List<string>(); // list to store the results

        // loop true the keys from every row
        // loop true the keys of the current row
        // check if tags contains key 
        // ckeck if lista already contains the key that was recognized(no duplicates in list)

        foreach (var value in messages.Keys)
            foreach (var value1 in value)
                if (tags.Contains(value1))
                    if(!lista.Contains(messages[value]))
                        lista.Add(messages[value]);
```

> Output

```
      ==========
      lista Count = 2
      1: Hello
      2: Bye!
```

Comment: Tried to implement this and expand upon it, but this error appears.
[link](http://imgur.com/a/EUiK0).

Also I see your variables dictionary has the key as simple string but I am using a string[] of items as key, does this work with that?

Comment: o thats because you have a string[] key as key in Dictionary and I have string as key, just a second and I'll fix it

Comment: It's better than what I had, but the problem still remains. At the end I need to have an array with the ones matching all the tags, now I have one with the ones matching any tag.

Comment: Using a `string[]` as the key in a Dictionary is not a typical thing to do.  Dictionaries are optimized for fast lookups based on a key, rather than as a container for iterating over. Having an array as a key means you can have strings appear twice as a key (e.g. "greeting"), which doesn't make sense for a Dictionary.  If possible, I would suggest you invert the data structure you're using to be a `Dictionary<string, string[]>` (e.g. "greeting" could map to "hello" and "goodbye"), or choose a different structure. Happy to provide more help if you can elaborate on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and your time. So far not much, just trying out different codes :)
Your code although does its job and I'm sure someone else will find it useful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may use simple class for searching by tags. This solution will improve abstraction level of your code.
Class example:

```
public class TagDictionary
{
    Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> _innerStorage = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();

    public void Add(IEnumerable<string> tags, string value)
    {
        foreach (var tag in tags)
        {
            if (_innerStorage.ContainsKey(tag))
            {
                var hash = _innerStorage[tag];
                if (!hash.Contains(value))
                {
                    hash.Add(value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _innerStorage[tag] = new HashSet<string>
                {
                    value
                };
            }
        }
    }

    public HashSet<string> GetValuesByTags(IEnumerable<string> tags)
    {
        var result = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (var tag in tags)
        {
            if (_innerStorage.ContainsKey(tag))
            {
                result.UnionWith(_innerStorage[tag]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Use example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var messages = new TagDictionary();
        messages.Add(new string[] { "greeting", "hello", "hei", "hi" }, "Hello!");
        messages.Add(new string[] { "greeting", "bye", "buh-bye", "sayonara" }, "Bye!");

        foreach (var value in messages.GetValuesByTags(new[] { "greeting", "hello" }))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
```

Just `string[]` is not good key type for standard `Dictionary`.